# prove for p(x) which is a quadratic polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

$p(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial . Prove that any given number for $a$ with one exception , we can find a number $b$ such that $p(a)=p(b)$ and $a$ is not equal to $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p(x) = mx^2 + nx + p, with m not equal to 0. Take p(b) - p(a) = m(b^2 - a^2) + n(b - a) = (b - a)(mb + ma + n). So given a, to get p(b) = p(a) choose b = -(ma +n)/m, then b is not equal a with the exception that a is not equal -n/2m which is the vertex of the parabola defined by p.

Comment: then 'b' equals to ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** By completing the square, we can express any quadratic polynomial $F(x)$ in the form
$$F(x)=p\left((x-q)^2+r\right)$$
where $p\ne 0$.